# ORA-01403 in Oracle-APEX Formular

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

Im having this Code. :P99_CAR, :P99_PARTS are Lists you can Select an ID (trough a lookup table), :P99_AMOUNT is a simple input in my form. So you select these 3 parts and want to check following code. So if PART_ID is 5, and CAR_ID is 3 and im selecting the same numbers from the list an ERROR is coming and i dont know why.

```
DECLARE
        --Varchar(100) or Number
      l_car Varchar(100);
      l_part Varchar(100);
    BEGIN
      SELECT CAR_ID, PART_ID INTO l_car, l_part FROM CAR_PARTS WHERE CAR_ID = :P99_CAR AND PARTS_ID = :P99_PARTS;
          IF l_car IS NULL OR l_parts IS NULL THEN 
              INSERT INTO CAR_PARTS (CAR_ID, PARTS_ID, CUR_AMOUNT) VALUES (:P99_CAR, :P99_PARTS, :P99_AMOUNT);
      ELSE
          UPDATE CAR_PARTS 
              SET CAR_ID = :P99_CAR,
                  PARTS_ID = :P99_PARTS,
                  CUR_AMOUNT = CUR_AMOUNT + :P99_AMOUNT
                      WHERE CAR_ID = :P99_CAR AND PARTS_ID = :P99_PARTS;
         END IF;
     END;
```

But im getting an ORA-01403 Error when Processing, and when submit this

> Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for Execute
>   PL/SQL Code.

I know I need to insert an Exception with that ERROR but why is it even coming?

Comment: In your SELECT you use :P99_CAR and :P99_PARTS in the WHERE clause of your UPDATE you use :P99_CAR_ID and :P99_PARTS_ID is this deliberate?

Comment: its the same was a mistake.

Comment: the thing is the insert is working. And the update is only working in the sql developer when im transforming the list and write 5 instead of :P99_CAR or 3 instead of :P99_PARTS so i guess this is the problem because with the explicit ids its working

Comment: I think you might want to investigate `merge`.

Comment: yes but merge with only one table ? i only know it with two @GordonLinoff

Comment: Run the page in debug mode. Once it fails, review the debug report and pay attention to what  values page items :P99_CAR and :P99_PARTS have; apparently, SELECT statement's WHERE clause causes no rows to be returned, and debug info might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` statement is not returning any rows. Since this works in a different environment, your bind variables aren't what you think they are. You should add calls to `apex_debug.message` in this process, then check what the values are in the debug log.

However, I would replace your entire process with a single merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO car_parts cp
USING ( SELECT :P99_CAR_ID AS car_id, :P99_PARTS ID AS parts_id, 
               :P99_CUR_AMOUNT AS cur_amount ) src
   ON ( cp.car_id = src.car_id AND cp.parts_id = src.parts_id )
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( car_id, parts_id, cur_amount )
      VALUES ( src.car_id, src.parts_id, src.cur_amount )
 WHEN MATCED THEN UPDATE SET cur_amount = src.cur_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that following query doesn't return any row:

```
SELECT CAR_ID, PART_ID INTO l_car, l_part FROM CAR_PARTS WHERE CAR_ID = :P99_CAR AND PARTS_ID = :P99_PARTS;
```

Try to wrap it in BEGIN END block and handle an exception:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT CAR_ID, PART_ID 
  INTO l_car, l_part 
  FROM CAR_PARTS 
  WHERE CAR_ID = :P99_CAR AND PARTS_ID = :P99_PARTS;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
-- Handle error here
END;
```

Comment: i just did it with this like you said:EXCEPTION 
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'No data found' );

Comment: and now the insert is working but still not the update. Like if its a new part and car its working, but not if its already exists

Comment: as i told in the other comment, in APEX i can only do the insert. And the Update is not working. But if i do the update in the sql developer with the above code and replace the lists (like :P99_CAR = 4 and :P99_PARTS = 2) then its working. So that means my code is right but maybe there is a syntax error or something wrong with the list idk